# can we measure our cardiovascular endurance from swimming?

Tags: exercise, swimming

as you know, cardiovascular endurance in swimming is something that cannot be avoided.

and I think, swimming will challenge our cardiovascular endurance more than other thing like running.

I'm looking forward to a way to measure my cardiovascular endurance in swimming Like its done by VO2max.

is it possible or is there any standard way to test it for a normal guy (Not for water polo athelte)?

there are lots of test which are just for water polo athletes: http://www.topendsports.com/testing/aerobic-swimming.htm

I don't believe they work for normal guys because they haven't got expert in it.

any answer appreciated.

**edit:**
I need it because I don't have sufficient equipments for VO2max test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the tests that you refer to at Top End are probably going to be your best bet at determining a VO2max for swimming. There are some testing setups where you are in an endless pool or flume, and wearing the expiration mask, but those are very specialized. If you want a water based test, the polo ones are the only ones I'm aware of.

However, VO2max is not that great a metric for determining current fitness or performance. VO2max is a measurement of capacity, and is a *predictor* for possible endurance sport aptitude, but that's about it.

As an example: If I plug in some numbers into the Rockport equation ([Calculator here](http://www.exrx.net/Calculators/Rockport.html)), it gives me a VO2max value. If all I do is drop my weight, my VO2max goes up, even if that is only accomplished by dieting and no extra fitness. If you are training, it's more of an academic number than a training metric.

A better indicator of performance is obtaining your vVO2max (Velocity or speed when you reach your VO2max level), and tlimvVo2max (Time limitation, or how long you can last at vVo2max). You can get a further explanation of these at [BrianMac](http://www.brianmac.co.uk/vvo2max.htm).

Comment: +1 for great explanation. and what about 1 mile run test?? is it something true or just a close value to our exact capacity??

Comment: @user3840019 - Unless you have a mask capturing and testing your exhaled air, any test you use is going to be an approximation. Some of them get close, but you can't do a run test and compare it to swimming, except as an abstract "Ok, so you've got potential" kind of way.